# How to extract particular Value from json response in Bean shell post processing and export it into CSV file

Tags: java, jmeter-5.0

I am using JMeter for load testing, each API give response in Json format. I need particular line(Particular Line) to export in CSV.

For e.g -> this is The Json Response

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": [
{
  "alert_id": "-1",
  "description": "Get Manager info",
  "input": "{"task_tag":"ad_manager_info","inputfields":[],"tenantcode":"rtech","token":"6wdd68-9d15-46b7-641c-9595ewsd5wedsd-1554717635279","isdemo":false}",
  "is_evidence": "n",
  "logo_path": "lib/log/abc.png",
  "name": "Get Manager Info",
  "processed": "y",
  "readstatus": "n",
  "requestid": "2118",
  "requesttime": "1554717797.07432",
  "response": {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
      "@odata.context": "https: //graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects/$entity",
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "bdg12-1257-XXXX-XXXX-4a8656b00171",
      "businessPhones": [

      ],
      "displayName": "MIC",
      "givenName": "MIC",
      "jobTitle": "Senior",
      "mail": null,
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": null,
      "preferredLanguage": null,
      "surname": "JANY",
      "userPrincipalName": "ABC@YAHoo.onmicrosoft.com"
    },
    "error": "",
    "status": "completed",
    "errorpath": "",
    "displaymessage": "",
    "sessionexpired": false
  },
  "responseid": "2119",
  "responsetime": "1554717802.52754",
  "task_handler": "ActiveDirectory",
  "tasktag": "ad_manager_info",
  "username": "ScottMcCall"
},

]
```

I need "description" "responsetime" only.

This is the code i am using

```
var a = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();
log.info("Value of A is --> " + a);

log.info("Value of Resposne is -->" + IDvalue)
   f = new FileOutputStream("E:/Result.csv");


p = new PrintStream(f);

FileWriter fr = new FileWriter("E:/Result.csv", true);

String b = a.description

log.info("Value of B is " + b)
```

Comment: Do you need help finding the values or writing them to a csv file? What does your code output now?

Comment: Both, my code is not able to find "description" in Json output. Only "getResponseDataAsString()" function is exporting whole JSON output in CSV fine. But i need only 2 things out of whole Json output (E.g -> above json output). 2 things which i want is "description" & "responsetime"